# How to get an extra day when adding 1 year to specific year

Tags: swift, swift3

My aim is to get an extra day when I add a year to a specific year:

**Playground:**

```
var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
var startDateString = "2015-01-05"
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

var startDate = dateFormatter.date(from: startDateString)
let result = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: 1, to: startDate!)
```

I expect to get `Jan 6, 2016, 12:00 AM`

Ok, I could get the result adding more code:

```
let finalResult = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: result!)
// January 6 etc...
```

Is there a simpler code for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add arbitrary "date components" in a single operation:

```
let dateComponents = DateComponents(year: 1, day: 1)
let result = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: startDate!)
```

`DateComponents` can also be used instead of a date formatter to *create*
a date, in your case:

```
let startDate = DateComponents(calendar: Calendar.current, year: 2015, month: 1, day: 5).date
```

Comment: So clean! I need to look at this DateComponents! Thank you!

Comment: @Sylar: You are welcome. – I have added another example how DateComponents can be used.